# Organizing and cleaning up a large website through best practices

Tags: html, css, structure, inline-styles

Ok, so I have always felt that had a good understanding of CSS until I got my current job. One of the first things they are having me work on is cleaning up their entire web-based accounting and inventory system. There are problems with cross compatibility. The system is extremely vast and has over 150 pages. The main problem is that the developer did not really use best practices when he developed the system (CSS). The system is setup with one stylesheet of with over 1800 lines of code, which really has no structure. The other major problem is that the website is mostly made with tables and a lot of the tables, as well as other elements have inline styles, specifically all of the input fields (sizes). To be honest, I am not sure the best way to approach this. Obviously, I want to pull out all of the inline styles out of the HTML. But finding the best way to go about doing this is hard. Any suggestions on the best way to move forward with this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My best advise is do it incrementally by breaking down the tasks into manageable modules, and do one a day. Something like:

- Use Firebug with Pagespeed extension to help you analyse the efficiency of your CSS and use the suggestions there as a roadmap to your overall refactoring.
- Remove all existing inline style by transferring them to an external **temp.css** file for example (*refresh very often to ensure that nothing breaks*).
- I will strongly advise looking at [Nicole Sullivan's work with OOCSS](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/) and pick one of her grids and the media object, most sites layout follow patterns that she covered very well with a very lean CSS.

You have the opportunity of making it right this time, so spend a lot of time in the proper planning of this. If you post some on fiddle I can help. Take care.